# How to translate a vector from an offset vector

Tags: vector, three.js, geometry, cad

How to translate a vector from an offset vector.

I have a line with 2 points attached one on the line start and one on the end vector of the line.

[image]

I want to translate the line and the points base on the DragConstrols position and not base on the line position I am just updating the line geometry vertices and the points position base on the line start and end vectors.

Keap in mind the points are not childs of the line, all objects are childs of the Scene
The line stores the points inside the userData of the line.

My goal is to translate all this 3 objects from the drag offset Vector3

Here is the screenshots of the line with the points.

`start_vector = (-140, 60, 0)
end_vector = (-70, 100, 0)`

I know the line start vector before the user drags the line `v1 = (-140, 60, 0)` and I
know the line end vector before the drag `v2 = (-70, 100, 0)`

Now when the user drags the line with the DragConstrols I dont let the dragControls to change the line position I get the dragConstrol vector3 and I want to translate the line vetrices base on that vector.

The DragControls allways start from `(0, 0, 0)` so I try to add the line vectors (v1, v2) with the position but I get this result.

[image]

Can someone show me how to set the line start and end vector from the dragControls position.
Or how to translate vectors from offset vectors.

Thank you.

My code so far.

Keep in mind the line is a Line2 (fat line) `three/examples/jsm/lines/Line2`

```js
class NewLine extends Line2 {

  private _start = new Vector3();
  private _end = new Vector3();

  /** The viewport width */
  public viewportWidth: number;

  /** The viewport height */
  public viewportHeight: number;

  /** The line3 */
  public line3 = new Line3();

  public get start() { return this._start; }
  public set start(v: Vector3) {
    this._start = v;
    this.line3.set(v, this._end);
    this.geometry['setPositions']([
      v.x,
      v.y,
      v.z,
      this._end.x,
      this._end.y,
      this._end.z
    ]);
    this.geometry['verticesNeedUpdate'] = true;  // maybe i don't need that
    this.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
    this.computeLineDistances();
  }

  public get end() { return this._end; }
  public set end(v: Vector3) {
    this._end = v;
    this.line3.set(this._start, v);
    this.geometry['setPositions']([
      this._start.x,
      this._start.y,
      this._start.z,
      v.x,
      v.y,
      v.z,
    ]);
    this.geometry['verticesNeedUpdate'] = true; // maybe i don't need that
    this.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
    this.computeLineDistances();
  }


  constructor( start: Vector3, end: Vector3 ) {
    super();

    // create geometry
    const geometry = new LineGeometry();
    geometry.setPositions([
      start.x, start.y, start.z,
      end.x, end.y, end.z
    ]);
    this.geometry = geometry;

    // create material
    const material = new LineMaterial({
      color: 0x000000,
      linewidth:5,
      depthTest: false, // new
      vertexColors: false,
    });
    this.material = material;

    this.computeLineDistances();
    this.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
    this.line3.set(start, end);

  }

}



/**
 * Translates a line base on DragControls position.
 * line: The NewLine
 * position: The new Vector3 position from dragControls
 */
translateLineFromVector(line: NewLine, position: Vector3) {

  const v1 = line.start;
  const v2 = line.end;

  const offset_start = line.start.clone().add( position ).sub(line.position);
  const offset_end = line.end.clone().add( position ).sub(line.position);

  line.start.copy( offset_start );
  line.end.copy( offset_end );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard approach for dragging:

```
On mouse down(X,Y):
    If Clicked at object and not Dragging:
         Dragging = True
         X0 = X
         Y0 = Y
         //important - remember object coordinates at this moment!
         V1_0 = V1
         V2_0 = V2

On mouse moving (X,Y) :
   If Dragging: 
       //Draw object at coordinates shifted by (X - X0), (Y - Y0)
       //from initial position, not from the current one
       V1.X = V1_0.X + X - X0
       V1.Y = V1_0.Y + Y - Y0
       same for V2
       DrawObject(V1,V2)


On Mouse Up(X,Y):
   If Dragging: 
       Fragging = False
       Fix positions V1,V2 if needed
```

Comment: Hi MBo Thank you for answering my question but I have already a system that handles the drag events, the probblem with that system is that the `onDragStart(x, y, z)` and the onDragMove(x, y, z) always start from (0, 0, 0). I need to some how use that vector in order to calculate the new Line vectors.

Thank you for your help MBo

Comment: Your picture reveals (accelerating flight away in drag direction)  inherent symptoms of what I emphasized: `from initial position, not from the current one`. I am not familiar with you code but perhaps `line.start.copy( offset_start );` does the unwanted trick